# Feature stopped working after changing data in the dictionary Python/PyQt5

Tags: python, button, pyqt5

I have everything sorted out with this little program of mine, however after I have inserted actual data i will be using into the dictionary, the button.setEnable(False) stopped working. Any ideas why?

code:

```
self.countBtn = QPushButton("Do something", self)
self.countBtn.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClick)

def onButtonClick(self):
        self.serversChecked = Worker()
        self.textOutput.clear()
        self.serversChecked.amount_of_servers.connect(self.setupUi)
        self.serversChecked.progress.connect(self.countCheckedServers)
        self.serversChecked.offline_servers.connect(self.toScreen)
        self.serversChecked.pbar_step.connect(self.pbar_step)
        self.serversChecked.amount_of_servers.connect(self.maxPbar)
        self.serversChecked.start()
        self.countBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.serversChecked.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.countBtn.setEnabled(True)
        )
```

This is all code i believe to be relevant, if more is needed, i can provide that.

Any ideas are welcome, as I am puzzled...

EDIT: as reqeusted, rest of code:

```
import sys, os, subprocess

from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPlainTextEdit,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    QProgressBar
)

class Worker(QThread):
    finished = pyqtSignal(str)
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)
    offline_servers = pyqtSignal(str)
    amount_of_servers = pyqtSignal(int)
    pbar_step = pyqtSignal(float)
    start_long_task = pyqtSignal(int)

    ips = {
        '001' : '142.250.178.14', '002' : '104.18.2.89', '003' : '10.251.63.23'
    }
    amount_of_servers_int = len(ips)

    def run(self):
        self.start_long_task.emit(1)
        amount_of_servers_int = len(self.ips)
        self.amount_of_servers.emit(amount_of_servers_int)

        with open(os.devnull, 'w') as DEVNULL:
            server = 0
            pbar_progress = 0
            for x, y in self.ips.items():
                try:
                    subprocess.check_call(
                    ['ping', '-n', '1', y],
                    stdout=DEVNULL,  # suppress output
                    stderr=DEVNULL
                    )
                except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                    nextServer = (working output here)
                    self.offline_servers.emit(nextServer)
                server = server + 1
                pbar_progress = pbar_progress + 1
                self.pbar_step.emit(pbar_progress)
                self.progress.emit(server)
        self.finished.emit('') 

class Window(QMainWindow):  

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()
        
    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("")
        self.resize(300, 400)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.textOutput = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.textOutput.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textOutput.resize(280, 300)
        self.textOutput.move(10, 5)

        self.serversCheckedtoScreen = QLabel("Checked: ", self)
        self.serversCheckedtoScreen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self, objectName="progressBar")  
        self.pbar.setGeometry(200, 80, 280, 20)
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        self.pbar.setMinimum(0)
        
        self.countBtn = QPushButton("Check Servers", self)
        self.countBtn.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClick)
        # Set the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.textOutput)
        layout.addWidget(self.serversCheckedtoScreen)
        layout.addWidget(self.pbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.countBtn)

        self.pbar.setStyleSheet("""
        QWidget {
            text-align: center;
            }
        """)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)

    def onButtonClick(self):
        self.serversChecked = Worker()
        self.textOutput.clear()
################This is the issue as pointed out by @musicamante ##########
        **self.serversChecked.amount_of_servers.connect(self.setupUi)**
################This piece of code shouldnt even be here, code blindness is a thing #####
        self.serversChecked.progress.connect(self.countCheckedServers)
        self.serversChecked.offline_servers.connect(self.toScreen)
        self.serversChecked.pbar_step.connect(self.pbar_step)
        self.serversChecked.amount_of_servers.connect(self.maxPbar)
        self.serversChecked.start_long_task.connect(self.disableButton)
        self.serversChecked.start()

        self.countBtn.setEnabled(False) ##### WHY IT DOESNT WORK

        self.serversChecked.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.countBtn.setEnabled(True)
        )

    def countCheckedServers(self, value):
        max = self.serversChecked.amount_of_servers_int
        self.serversCheckedtoScreen.setText(f"Servers Checked: {value} / " + str(max))

    def toScreen(self, value):
        self.textOutput.appendPlainText(value)
    
    def pbar_step(self, value):
        self.pbar.setValue(int(value))

    def maxPbar(self,value):
        self.pbar.setMaximum(value)
    
    def disableButton(self, n): # added extra function to check but makes no difference
        if n == 1:
            self.countBtn.setDisabled(True)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: I tried moving setEnabled() to a function to see if this will change things and create a starting pyqtSignal for this purpose, however it hasnt changed anything. Still stuck...

Comment: Sorry, but your code is insufficient to understand the problem. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Right now your code is not reproducible, as we don't know if the data in `ips` is valid or not. For what we know, all addresses could be invalid, which would make ping return instantly, thus "keeping" the button enabled (since it was disabled just for a fraction of a second).

Comment: @musicamante I have hidden the data for security reasons, however It runs perfecty fine, going through the list and outputs those that are offline. You can check any data, any publicly accessible server and see that it works, however button wont react

Comment: You don't have to provide the *original* data, you have to provide data that allows your code and issue to be *reproducible*. Don't make us look for lists of servers that might and/or might not work, that's your part: ours is to find if the problem actually exists and eventually provide a solution. Besides that, how many servers do you check?

Comment: @musicamante small example added, in produciton over 1000, and apologies, im still learning the standards of SO, thakn you for your time and understanding

Comment: You're calling `self.setupUi` everytime the worker is started, so you're creating a new UI. That signal is not emitted instantly, but asynchronously. So, the button *is* disabled, but right after that the thread is actually started, which creates a *new* UI, with an enabled button. Remove `self.serversChecked.amount_of_servers.connect(self.setupUi)`.

Comment: I hate code blindness... I dont even know why it was there, i removed this line long time ago.... Thank you so much for your help! could you make a comment with this answer so i can mark it up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239890/discussion-between-gregory-sky-and-musicamante).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by @musicamante in the comments, I have left a line of code under

```
def onButtonClick(self):
        self.serversChecked = Worker()
        self.textOutput.clear()
```

After removing

```
self.serversChecked.amount_of_servers.connect(self.setupUi)
```

As per his advise the problem has been solved. I have asked him to create an asnwer so I can credit him and I hope he does so soon. As such i am not marking as complete yet.

Copy of his original comment in the meantime:

> You're calling `self.setupUi` everytime the worker is started, so you're creating a new UI. That signal is not emitted instantly, but asynchronously. So, the button is disabled, but right after that the thread is actually started, which creates a new UI, with an enabled button. Remove `self.serversChecked.amount_of_servers.connect(self.setupUi)`.

Sadly, code blindness is a thing, however, there are some remarkable people willing to help. Again, Thank you @musicamante

Comment: Don't worry, you've already properly answered it (I wouldn't have, as I believe your question falls in the category of not reproducible/typo), you can mark it as accepted as soon as the system allows it (usually, 2 days).